# dsb_sc of sin wave

Tags: communication, digital-communications

Can we take the dsb_sc(Double side band suppressed carrier)of a sinusoidal signal I know that it exists for cosine but for sine I can't find anything on the internet

Answer (score 0):

Cosine signal is 90 degrees phase shifted sine. In many modulation formulas the carrier is presented with cos(wt) instead of sine.

Nobody prevents one writing the modulation formulas with carrier sin(wt), but for some reason it isn't the standard in textbooks. I bet the reason is somehow handier equations with cos altough the properties of the modulation do not become different. DSB with or without suppressed carrier thus works equally, no matter is the carrier sine or 90 degrees phase shifted sine.